# powering arduino and servo with a single battery

Tags: arduino, battery, servo

I have been struggling to power up a servo and arduino at the same time. Is it possible to connect a 3.7v 2200mah battery using a step up voltage regulator and then connect the servo and arduino in parallel? I also want to charge the battery, that's why I want to use a single battery. Thank you

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about powering hardware, not programming.

Answer (score -1):

Arduino board has an internal voltage regulator, so if you will supply a voltage less than 5 it won't work. You better need to have at least 5v for the battery and then you can connect both aurdino and servo motor. 
Using [powerbank](http://assets.hardwarezone.com/img/2014/12/Mi-16000mAh-ports.jpg) can be a good option